# Несовпадение типов в таблице MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Браузер выдает ошибку несоответствия переменных в этой строке:

```
$last_id = $last_id + 1;
```

В таблице id давал значение int.
Вот код программы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register submit</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require "scripts/dbconnect.php";
    $first_name = $_REQUEST["first_name"];
    $last_name = $_REQUEST["last_name"];
    $test_for_last_id = "select * from users where id = (select max(id) from users);";
    $resultmq = mysqli_query($link, $test_for_last_id) or die ("<div>Ошибка проверки последнего id</div>");
    $last_id = mysqli_fetch_row($resultmq);
    $last_id = $last_id + 1;
    $add_data_in_db = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('".$last_id."', '".$first_name."','".$last_name."')";
    mysqli_query($link, $add_data_in_db);
    ?>
    <h1>Добрый день, <?php echo $first_name; echo $last_name; ?></h1>
    <button><a href="afterrg.html">Привет</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Функция возвращает массив при правильном функционировании http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Что тогда использовать?

Comment: Да вообще-то для этой цели используют атрибут `AUTO_INCREMENT` у нужного поля при создании таблицы. И он дает указание базе данных автоматически присваивать номер новой строке. http://blog.nagaychenko.com/2011/03/11/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-last_insert_id-%D0%B8-auto_increment-%D0%B2-mysql/